# Finding monthly average from weekly data for every company

Tags: r, dplyr

Hello I am new to R and I'm trying to find the monthly average of ownership data from weekly data for every company. It consists of 3 different sheets of weekly data from 2009 to 2020 for many companies and I merged them all together into one data frame. The data looks something like this, "tarih" means "Date", mbr_id represents the companies, and "mulkiyet_bakiye" represents the ownership level that I'm trying find the monthly average of.

```
> head(df)
# A tibble: 6 x 3
  tarih      mbr_id mulkiyet_bakiye
  <date>     <chr>            <dbl>
1 2009-01-02 A         1083478.
2 2009-01-02 B         1624843.
3 2009-01-02 C        90340363.
4 2009-01-02 D          2128114.
5 2009-01-02 E       47541783.
6 2009-01-02 F          268874.
```

I've tried something like this so far: (This solution was for another problem, but I thought maybe it would work for this one)

```
df$tarih <- as.Date(df$tarih, format = '%Y-%m-%d')

monthly_average <- df %>%
    mutate(year = year(tarih), month = month(tarih), week = week(tarih)) %>%
    unite_("date", c("year", "month", "week"), sep ="-") %>%
    group_by(date, mbr_id) %>%
    summarise(monthly_mean_owner = mean(mulkiyet_bakiye)) %>% 
    arrange(mbr_id)
```

However, the result looks like this:

```
> head(monthly_average,10)
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   date [10]
   date       mbr_id monthly_mean_owner
   <chr>      <chr>               <dbl>
 1 2009-1-1   A            1083478.
 2 2009-1-2   A            1083478.
 3 2009-1-3   A            1083478.
 4 2009-1-4   A            1083478.
 5 2009-1-5   A            1083588.
 6 2009-10-40 A             993589.
 7 2009-10-41 A             993589.
 8 2009-10-42 A             993589.
 9 2009-10-43 A             993589.
10 2009-10-44 A            993589.
```

I think I've made mistake while arranging the dates, but I don't know how to fix it.
Could someone help me do that? (Or another way to do this calculation?)
Thanks and appreciating your response.

Comment: If you data is already weekly data then `group_by(year, month, mbr_id)` should do the job.

Comment: I tried to do this and it said "Column `year` is not found. Column `month` is not found." although I just added them in the mutate part.

Comment: That's probably because of `unite` which removes the original columns by default. But you could get rid of this line or add `remove=FALSE` to unite.